# Sexting in iddah period with husband pretending to be some random different girl. Is my divorce valid?

Tags: talaq, iddah

I am sunni. We follow 3 divorce system. My husand sent me 1st divorce but i started sexting with him & shared nude images of a random different girl pretending to be her on social media platform. He was also indulged in sexual explicit talks & sent me his real nude pictures.I kept doing it thru out my 3 divorces. i.e in iddah period. After divorce i stopped did toba. Is my divorce valid & does this mean he raj'u (arabic) me during divorce as we were both involved in sexting? He never touched me physically never did we had any sexual relations physically. It was all virtual and i was pretending to be some different random girl. He didnt know it was me.